# Flutter Firebase_Admob "The Google Mobile Ads SDK requires a deployment target of iOS 8.0 or later." iOS error

Tags: ios, firebase, build, flutter, admob

I am consistently getting the "The Google Mobile Ads SDK requires a deployment target of iOS 8.0 or later." error when trying to build my Flutter project in iOS.  I've updated the workspace to the Legacy Build System, changed my target to 9.0, updated the podfile, and added the necessary entry on my infoplist.  Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The Google-Mobile-Ads podspec did recently update its minimum iOS version in the [7.43.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/7.43.0/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.podspec.json#L34) release. I'm not sure why it would be a problem if your Podfile includes `platform :ios, '8.0'`. One workaround might be to go back to [Google-Mobile-Ads 7.42.2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/7.42.2/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.podspec.json#L34) with `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads', '7.42.2'` to support back to iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Answer? I may break something doing this, but I simply commented out the "if" statement in the Google Mobile Ads SDK

```
//#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_8_0
//#error The Google Mobile Ads SDK requires a deployment target of iOS 8.0 or later.
//#endif
```

It works for me now. If anyone knows a more valid way of doing this or if I should never do this please comment on this post.